# Sharepoint SE cannot connect with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio

I am getting this error when I am trying to create a new SharePoint empty project from visual studio

**I am getting SharePoint connection error**.

[image]

I have checked those steps:

1. Run VS as administrator
   2.The user is set as sysadmin of the SQLServer, as well as db_owner of the following DBs.
   a. WSS_Content

   b. Sharepoint_Admin_Content

   c. Sharepoint_Config
2. The user is owner of the SP and has full control.
3. The site is added to the IIS host file.
4. I have cleared VS cache.

This also occur when I am trying to import SharePoint Solution File. (.wsp)

I am using SharePoint Server Subscription Edition and Visual Studio 2022 Community.

Thanks,

---

This was solution for me.

• Step1: Download and install WebPI (https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)

• Step2: Install Workflow Manager (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/workflow-manager/jj193525(v=azure.10))

Service Bus 1.1 with TLS1.2 support

Workflow Manager 1.0 Refresh (CU2)

Workflow Manger Client 1.0 Cumulative Update4

Workflow Manger Client 1.0 Cumulative Update5

• Step3: Create a new farm, see (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/workflow-manager/jj193514(v=azure.10))

• Step4: Configure according to Install and Configure workflow for SharePoint Server (https://docs.microsoft.com/EN-US/sharepoint/governance/install-and-configure-workflow-for-sharepoint-server)

• Step5: Restart your machine

Comment: Are you running Visual Studio on one of the SharePoint servers?

Comment: Yes, the VS is installed on the server, also it is run as Administrator.

Comment: Sorry for bumping, but I have the same issue, and WebPI had its EOL last month. Are you sure installing Workflow manager is the only solution to this problem?